# REST routing in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, rest, routes

Basic question,

I have a nice and working Zend REST serivce, I've done the necessary routing and everyting is working as it should. However, my REST service is just one controller. The other controllers have to have the zend default routing because they are used for actions and views.

How do I make a route that points to the REST route when a controller is called and points to a controller/action when I want to view my website?

or in other word: I need a 'controller specific' route.

Comment: How did you do the routing for the REST part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer on the official Zend website. You can Rest_Route to a specific controller by giving an array of controllernames to the zend_rest function. Like this:

```
    class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    public function _initRoutes()
    {

        $this->bootstrap("Frontcontroller");
        $front = $this->getResource('Frontcontroller');
        $front->throwExceptions(false);
        $router = $front->getRouter();
        $restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($front, array(), array(
            'default' => array('YourControllerName')
        ));
        $router->addRoute('rest', $restRoute);

    }
}
```